# Copy subset of a std::map

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy a subset of a std::map structure to a new map structure in the most efficient way. I can only think to a plain vanilla solution like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  // build map
  std::map<int, int> mymap;
  size_t num_el = 10;


  for(size_t i = 0; i < num_el; ++i)
  {
      mymap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(i,i));
  }

 // copy submap
 int start_index = 5;
 std::map<int,int> output_map;
 std::map<int,int>::const_iterator it;

  for(it = mymap.find(start_index); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
  {
       output_map.insert(*it);
  }


  //print result
  std::map<int,int>::const_iterator pit;
  for(pit = output_map.begin(); pit != output_map.end(); ++pit)
  {
     std::cout << pit->second << " , ";   
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert method allows you to specify a range like so:

```
auto range_start = mymap.find(5);
auto range_end = mymap.end();

output_map.insert(range_start, range_end);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want additional flexibility on choice of the copied elements, `copy_if` will provide it:

```
std::copy_if(
    begin(mymap),
    end(mymap),
    std::inserter(output_map, begin(output_map)),
    [&start_index](std::pair<int,int> p) { return p.first >= start_index; }
);
```

It's a bit tricky to use it for `std::map` (and also e.g. `std::set`), but `std::inserter` works nicely.

Of course the simpler `std::copy` could be used similarly to the range constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map range constructor (c++11):

```
std::map<int,int> output_map{mymap.find(start_index), mymap.end()};
```

and if you need older standard:

```
std::map<int,int> output_map( mymap.find(start_index), mymap.end() );
```

And insert works too

Comment: or c++14  (range constructor) ?