# what is the most elegant way of returning a lot of std::map<,>::iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I am working on a car fleet program that has a container that contains a lot of cars

```
std::map<CarKey, Car> _cars;
```

I need to write a function/class that operate on a subset of the car objects in the _cars

Naively I can just iterate through _cars with a filter function

```
for(auto& p : _cars){
    //please note: I cannot get things done with one iteration, I have to iterate many times to get things done
    if (isOfInterest(p.second)){
        // do some thing
    }
}
```

the downside of such a solution is that is I am interested only in 10% of the cars, I will have to waste a lot time iterating

I am trying to find an elegant way to return all the iterators that I am interested

```
std::vector<std::map<CarKey, Car> :: iterator > getAllIntereted(_cars)
```

then I can simply iterate through the vector

I am not sure if this is a good approach. Maybe there is some design pattern that can be helpful?

Can anyone give any insights?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is helpful if interesting cars are within a range and you grap them as a new map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080489/copy-subset-of-a-stdmap

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem confirmed by a profiler?

Comment: Your code looks totally fine to me. If you want to improve the performance, try to make `isOfInterest()` efficient, e.g. by caching, if some complex lookup is involved.

Comment: You certainly can have a vector of iterators (or may be even better, non-owning pointers) to elements in your map, and this will improve the performance by removing all those branches. However, you might be better of by improving algorithmic complexity.

Comment: As a caveat, pay very close attention to when iterators become invalidated when the container changes.  Different containers have different promises for when iterators are invalidated.

Comment: How often do you iterate and filter?

Comment: *I will have to waste a lot time iterating* -- Depending on the type that `CarKey` is, maybe a `std::unordered_map` would be better, since it works via hash key?

Comment: If you reveal your getAllIntereted function, then it may help us to give you better solutions.

Till now, it seems quiet good.

Comment: if you only care about car but not carkey, may be you can cache it to vector of pointer/reference_wrapper of interested cars.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, I think returning a vector containing pointers to just the cars you are interested in is a good solution. Pointers because otherwise you are creating duplicate objects.

However, if you can just do the work in the same loop that you identify the car, I think that would be best. Just depends on if that is practical.